# Breaking the loop after checking the result from observable in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I would like to break the loop after checking the condition from the return of observable. When the status is False, I want to exit the loop. I have the below code:

```
var response = Observable<responseService>;
var i;
for (i =0; i < lin.length; i++){
 response = this.http.post<responseService>(this.Url, {}, options).pipe(
    map(data => {
      return data;
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      return of(null);
      }
    ));

  var res = response.map(x => x.status);
  console.log(res);
  if (res === "False" || res === null) {
    response{
     status: "FALSE",
     message: "ERROR"
    }
   return of(response);
  }
}
return response;
```

But I am getting error for the if condition as below

*"The condition will always return false since the types 'Observable <>' and 'string' has no overlap".*

I would greatly appreciate if anyone knows what I am doing wrong or have solution. Thank you!

Comment: this is asyn call until your if condition, request may not finish. Use await to read  observable to wait until answer

Answer (score 0):

1. You aren't subscribing the observable and trying to compare an observable to a string. When you compare `if (res === "False" || res === null)`, `res` variable is still an observable.
2. Having nested subscriptions isn't a good practice. And it won't help you here if you wish to make each request sequentially until one request emits `False` or if `null`.

You could try create an array of requests and subscribe to it sequentially using RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) function and [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) operator. Then break the sequence using the [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator if the condition is satisfied. Try the following

```js
import { Subject, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

private getData() {
  let closeRequest$ = new Subject<any>();
  let response = Observable<responseService>;
  let requests = Observable<responseService>[];
  for (let i =0; i < lin.length; i++) {
    requests.push(this.http.post<responseService>(this.Url, {}, options))   // <-- don't map response here
  }

  from(requests).pipe(
    concatMap(request => of(request)),
    takeUntil(closeRequest$)
  ).subscribe(
    response => {
      if (!response['status'] && response['status'] === "False") {    // <-- check for `response.status` truthiness
        // response is false
        this.someVar = { status: "FALSE", message: "ERROR" };
        this.closeRequest$.next();
        this.closeRequest$.complete();
      } else {
        this.someVar = status;
      }
    },
    error => { }
  );
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error for conditional check. @Michael D

Comment: @CodeVenture: Then you're doing something else than what I've did. Please post what you're attempting now in the question.

Comment: I've also updated the code to check for `status` property truthiness instead of comparing it to `null`.

Comment: How are you getting status property from response? Intelisense is not showing the property status. It is complaining about it does not exist in the observable<responseService>.

Comment: That's a TS lint error. Replace dot with bracket notation. I've edited the answer. It won't affect the actual program since at runtime the property would be available.

Comment: And instead of ||, is not that should be && for the condition?

Comment: I was using the same condition you used in the question. You could change it according to your wish.

Comment: Now there is no error. So from the condition when the status is FALSE, then the final result in this.someVar will be status: false and message: error. If I am correct

Comment: Yes, but not when the status is `FALSE` but `False`. The string literal comparison is case sensitive. Please check if the status is `False` or `FALSE` or `false` and check accordingly.

Comment: And I have to check if the response's status property is null, then we should assign this.someVar, the same value false and close the request. What condition it will have then. Is it if ((!response['status'] && response['status'] === "False") || response['status'] === null)

Comment: If you mean by `null` that the property `status` doesn't exist in the `response` object, then the condition `!response['status']` should take care of it. This condition is true when the `status` property isn't found. If you're still uncertain you can do `if (response['status'] === "False" || response['status'] === null || response['status'] === undefined)`.

Comment: We have defined the status and message property in the responseService so it must have. If you agree. I have declared export interface responseService{status: string; message: string;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216226/discussion-between-michael-d-and-codeventure).